# We have used Filter sand for construction , Is there a problem in this sand?

Tags: construction

We have used filter sand to construct our home and for mold we have used trichy sand, The building is almost completer just final Flor is pending, Now many people come to me and say that we are using wrong sand this sand is not so good for construction. Is there anything I can do about this Please do let me know if there is anything.

Comment: I don't understand, how did you use sand to construct a building? Are you referring to the sand used in concrete?

Comment: If you have already cast the concrete, there's nothing you can do to change the sand within the concrete. I don't know whether there's a problem or not; the questions would seem to be what size the sand grains are, what mineral they're made of, possibly their shape (though I think that's unlikely to be an issue).

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir but I dont know how to test the sand and those size i think i could send u some pic's. Yes we already have concrete just final floor is pending. it will be done in few weeks too I am just holding it and asking some experts if there is anything I can do.

Comment: I used filter sand, which is a high silica sand with very round particles, the cement ended up being very flaky since there was not a good bond to the sand particles. i definitely think, if your sand is the same it will affect the strength

Comment: I am feeling the same but the building has come up with a good and is strong all I am scared if about feature and the contractor says it is not a filter sand is there any way i can test the sand?

Comment: @srikanath bhatt I think that You can take a sample of this sand and try to contact some academics (technical iniversities got laboratories for that). I bet they would happily answer Your question, and some students may we willing to do some work with it.

Comment: Sharp sand, completely washed of all organic content. Anything else and you have weak concrete. If you didn't spec it before the concrete mix, you just have to accept the consequences, except in countries with building standards, at which point you will be getting in equipment to rip out everything where the substandard concrete pour happened. Try being the idiot contractor that did this to Walmart locally, one less concrete company in the area as remediation bankrupted them.

Answer (score 1):

I had to Google Trichy and filter sand to try to decipher your question.

I'm guessing you mean you are using river sand from the Trichy area (Bangalore, India).  For structural concrete, you should have sand (about 1 mm), gravel (5 to 20 mm), and cement.

If you have sand but no gravel, that is not good.  Gravel but no sand, also not good.

Some sand is dirty, with clay or organic material, and that is not good...but you say filter sand so that should be clean.  Some sand is too round/smooth to make a good bond and some, like crushed coral or pumice, is too soft.

In US we have very specific mix designs, test the sand and gravel, and we break samples of cured concrete to make sure it is as strong as advertised before removing formwork or shoring.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any way we can test the sand that I am using now? If there is any please do let me know about it I will be very much thankful.

Comment: @srikanth bhatt Look at my comment to Your question. Technical universities can test it and describe its value. As for 'concrete' with Your sand, read _scolier_'s answer, gravel is mandatory ingredient for that, so You need to take a sample of gravel for anyone to test Your concrete.

Comment: @MarekOleszczuk Why is aggregate mandatory? I was under the impression that is used for fill. Without it you just have 'super-crete'. Sand composition *is* very important though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand when sand prices went high certain unscrupulous elements dug out mud and repeatedly washed it, to produce what is called as filter sand, near Herbal Bangalore a school girl was killed when a wall collapsed which was made of filter sand. Ever since the govt has banned use of this sand. Finally you can do a test yourself take some sand and put it in water you will find a lot if silt and mud which does not provide good bonding, if you still want to use it Pls increase proportion of cement,  and never use for concrete and building foundations. 
It could be used for plastering? Pls consult experts.